# Not able to write the correct code for java pattern

Tags: java

How to print this pattern using for loop and please explain the steps using comment lines

123454321

1234_4321

123___321

12_____21

1_______1

i know how to write the left part only or the right part only but i don't know how to input the correct number of "_" in between. Don't send me the code itself, just tell me how to do it

And no this is not my homework

** My solution **

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int pointer = 6;
    for(int i=0; i<=5; i++){

        for(int j = 1; j<= i; j++){
            if(pointer > j || j == 1) {
                System.out.print(j);
            } else {
                System.out.print("_");
            }
        }

        for(int j = 4; j > 0; j--) {
            if(pointer > j || j == 1) {
                System.out.print(j);
            } else {
                System.out.print("_");
            }
        }

        pointer--;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: No! Im studying for finals and i saw this question online and im not able to solve it. I dont understand how to put the  5 once only for the first line and then to put _ for all the others

Comment: This seems like a typical puzzle problem to teach you how to write simple routines.  It would be in your best interests to figure it out for yourself.  Because you will be hopelessly lost later if you can't figure this out.

Comment: @durbnpoisn *"...you will be hopefully lost later..."* Wow I laughed way too hard at that.

Comment: I would say you have to know the full length. And by your example it is 9 - 1 to 5 and then 4 to 1. This tells you how many _ you have. It is each row one number. You could for example just have a check, where you look up if your current pointer is less then the number you want to show. If so, then you can write the number, otherwise you write the _. So in your first row the pointer is 6 and writes all the numbers, in the next round the pointer is one less. That way you omit the number 5. And it goes on till you reach the number 1, which is always displayed.

Comment: Hint: Start with a full up string then gradually remove bits. It is simpler than it looks

Comment: @Blah Does the solution have to be a general solution? Or is it enough to assume you are always dealing with that output? From the code you updated, it seems like you want a general solution. I am asking to better understand what solution are you looking for.

Comment: That specific output

Comment: Hey @Blah I posted the answer down. With my edit from your post the wanted output still would not be shown. Just check my answer down and you should get the right output for each line. I really hope this is the solution you desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
    String numbers = "123454321";
    String[] remove = new String[]{"5", "4", "3", "2"};
    System.out.println(numbers);
    for (String current : remove) {
        numbers = numbers.replace(current, "_");
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
```

Coded without the use of an array:

```
    String numbers = "123454321";
    System.out.println(numbers);
    for (int x = 5; x > 1; x--) {
        numbers = numbers.replace(Integer.toString(x), "_");
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
```

Comment: I like how OP's name is Blah and yours is blahfunk

Comment: Imitation is the highest form of flattery :)

Comment: i know how to do it using arrays, i just don't understand how to do it using for loops...

Comment: But he did use a for loop. he loops through the `collection`. This is even better then my design @Blah

Comment: for my midterms we were ask to do something like that without using arrays, we had to use for loops only and i want to know how to do it

Comment: @Blah why did you accept the answer if it's not what you need to know?

Comment: Because he's trying to help while everybody's making fun of me

Answer (score 1):

From what I wrote it would be the same as I edited your text up:

```
int pointer = 6;

for(int i=5;i>0;i--) {

    // writing number from 1 to 5
    // number 1 is always displayed
    for(int j=1;j<6;j++) {
        if(pointer > j || j == 1) {
            System.out.print(j);
        } else {
            System.out.print("_");
        }
    }

    // writing number from 4 to 1
    // number 1 is always displayed
    for(int j=4;j>0;j--) {
        if(pointer > j || j == 1) {
            System.out.print(j);
        } else {
            System.out.print("_");
        }
    }

    // To add the line end and subtract the pointer
    System.out.println("");
    pointer--;
}
```

The general solution, where n is the highest number.

```
int pointer = n+1;

for(int i=n;i>0;i--) {

    // writing number from 1 to 5
    // number 1 is always displayed
    for(int j=1;j<n+1;j++) {
        if(pointer > j || j == 1) {
            System.out.print(j);
        } else {
            System.out.print("_");
        }
    }

    // writing number from 4 to 1
    // number 1 is always displayed
    for(int j=n-1;j>0;j--) {
        if(pointer > j || j == 1) {
            System.out.print(j);
        } else {
            System.out.print("_");
        }
    }

    // To add the line end and subtract the pointer
    System.out.println("");
    pointer--;
}
```

Comment: can you help me how to fix this please

 i'm editing my post

Comment: @JernejK why not generalize it now? (Also, there's something other than a "5" that you'd need to replace). Also, this doesn't actually print the right pattern (no underscores).

Comment: So I changed the logic a bit, now it should work if you want those kind of for loops @Blah. Of course you can easily shift the logic for checking in a method, because you can easily shrink down the number of lines. As you can see I used the `print` and not `println`. That way it gets written in the same line. Hope that helps you if this is what you were looking for. With your example the variable n would be 5.

Comment: @Blah I wrote to you also here the specific solution.

Comment: And I double checked that it works, and it does @Blah. I also had I minor bug in it, but you are safe to take the code from my answer.

Comment: This is my output `123454321 1234_4321 123___321 12_____21 1_______1` @Blah. It is the same one as your posted up.

Comment: Why `print("" + j)`? Shouldn't `print(j)` be easier to read and more efficient?

Comment: You are right, I forgot the method is overloading and can take various types and print them. I will correct that @Clashsoft

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for your question

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i=0;
    int count=0;
    for (i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if(j!=5)
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        if (i!=0) {
            for (int m = 0; m < count; ++m) {
                System.out.print("_");
            }
        }
        for (int k = i; k > 0; k--) {
            System.out.print(k);
        }
        System.out.println();
        ++count;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you